# Grouping rows with mutliple conditions across columns, incl. a sorting, in R/dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In the following dataframe, I have 24 points in the 3D space (2 horizontal locations along X and Y, each with 12 vertical values along Z).

I would like to group together the points vertically if:

- they have the same `val` value ***and***
- they follow each other along the Z axis (so two `1` separated by another value would not have the same ID).

And this should be done only for the values beyond the 3 first Z values (which automatically get ID = 1, 2 and 3 respectively, the following ones start at 4).

```
set.seed(50)
library(dplyr)
mydf = data.frame(X = rep(1, 24), Y = rep(1:2, each = 12), 
                  Z = c(sample(1:12,12,replace=F), sample(4:16,12,replace=F)),
                  val = c(rep(1:3, 8)))
mydf = mydf %>% group_by(X,Y) %>% arrange(X,Y,Z) %>% data.frame()
#    X Y  Z val
# 1  1 1  1   3 # In this X-Y location, Z starts at 1
# 2  1 1  2   3
# 3  1 1  3   3
# 4  1 1  4   2
# 5  1 1  5   2
# 6  1 1  6   1
# 7  1 1  7   1
# 8  1 1  8   1
# 9  1 1  9   1
# 10 1 1 10   2
# 11 1 1 11   2
# 12 1 1 12   3
# 13 1 2  4   2 # In this X-Y location, Z starts at 4
# [etc (see below)]
```

Desired output (note for example that lines 4-5 and 10-11 get a different `ID`):

```
rle1 = rle(mydf[4:12,]$val)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:4] 2 4 2 1
#   values : int [1:4] 2 1 2 3
rle2 = rle(mydf[4:12 + 12,]$val)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:7] 2 1 1 2 1 1 1
#   values : int [1:7] 3 1 2 1 3 1 2
mydf$ID = c(1:3, rep(4:(3+length(rle1$lengths)), rle1$lengths),
            1:3, rep(4:(3+length(rle2$lengths)), rle2$lengths))
#    X Y  Z val ID
# 1  1 1  1   3  1
# 2  1 1  2   3  2
# 3  1 1  3   3  3
# 4  1 1  4   2  4
# 5  1 1  5   2  4
# 6  1 1  6   1  5
# 7  1 1  7   1  5
# 8  1 1  8   1  5
# 9  1 1  9   1  5
# 10 1 1 10   2  6
# 11 1 1 11   2  6
# 12 1 1 12   3  7 # In this X-Y location, I have 7 groups in the end
# 13 1 2  4   2  1
# 14 1 2  5   2  2
# 15 1 2  6   3  3
# 16 1 2  7   3  4
# 17 1 2  9   3  4
# 18 1 2 10   1  5
# 19 1 2 11   2  6
# 20 1 2 12   1  7
# 21 1 2 13   1  7
# 22 1 2 14   3  8
# 23 1 2 15   1  9
# 24 1 2 16   2 10 # In this X-Y location, I have 10 groups in the end
```

How could I perform this more efficiently, or in one line, and why not with `dplyr`, supposing this applies for many (X,Y) locations and with always the 3 first Z values (which starts at a different value at each location) followed by a location-dependent number of following `ID` groups?

I was starting with a try to work with a vector from a conditional subset in `dplyr`, which is wrong:

```
mydf %>% group_by(X,Y) %>% arrange(X,Y,Z) %>%
  mutate(dummy = mean(rle(val)$values))
```

> Error: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': Error in rle(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L))$function (x,  : 
>     invalid subscript type 'closure'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table::rleid` on `val` starting from the 4th element and then add an offset of 3, this could simplify the `rle` calculation;

```
library(dplyr); library(data.table)
mydf %>% 
    group_by(X, Y) %>% 
    mutate(ID = c(1:3, rleid(val[-(1:3)]) + 3)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()    # for print purpose only

#   X Y  Z val ID
#1  1 1  1   3  1
#2  1 1  2   3  2
#3  1 1  3   3  3
#4  1 1  4   2  4
#5  1 1  5   2  4
#6  1 1  6   1  5
#7  1 1  7   1  5
#8  1 1  8   1  5
#9  1 1  9   1  5
#10 1 1 10   2  6
#11 1 1 11   2  6
#12 1 1 12   3  7
#13 1 2  4   2  1
#14 1 2  5   2  2
#15 1 2  6   3  3
#16 1 2  7   3  4
#17 1 2  9   3  4
#18 1 2 10   1  5
#19 1 2 11   2  6
#20 1 2 12   1  7
#21 1 2 13   1  7
#22 1 2 14   3  8
#23 1 2 15   1  9
#24 1 2 16   2 10
```

Or without `rleid`, use `cumsum` + `diff`:

```
mydf %>% group_by(X, Y) %>% mutate(ID = c(1:3, cumsum(c(4, diff(val[-(1:3)]) != 0))))
```